# home malting equipment

Tags: equipment, malt

I wonder if you guys use any home malting equipment. Or is there such equipment available for homebrewers? I'd like to use automated malting equipment up to 25kg-50kg/batch. If you know such equipment, please share.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I've done a bit of home malting. Nothing automated except the drying process in a dehydrator. Some people have created rotary malting machines that rotate the grain. That is so you don't have to turn it by hand. But you'll need to build it yourself. I did a pretty extensive search into this last year and there is nothing available to the home maltster. You can get commercial equipment but it would take up quite a large space in a warehouse and cost a lot of money.

Malting at home is fairly easy and you can do quite a lot with simple tools. Drying is the tricky part and home dehydrators are perfect for this. Some people turn old clothes driers into dehydrators. Good luck!

Comment: Have you tried microwave or electric oven? Do you think microwave oven affects malt?

Comment: @user8852720 microwaves excite the water in food to generate the heat. Idk how it would turn out, but may range of bad effects from making popcorn to at least denaturing all enzymes.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is old but if anyone still interested it should Google 'sprowt labs malting acro'. They make some automated home malting thing that malts enough grain to make triple batch of beer. They are US based so there is no 230V support.